# React JS: How to add a new row while clicking the button, each row have same component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, material-ui

Developer, I am a new react js. I have a component. My component has a select dropdown control, TextField control, TextAreaAutoSize control, and button.
While I click the button Dropdown(Select), TextField control, TextAreaAutoSize control, and Button added to another row. It's iterated based on the click button. After adding the new row, the previous row clicks the button changed to the remove button. While I click the remove button row control will be removed. how to do this.

I attached the CodeSandBox Link:
[Add component automatically while clicking the button & delete component automatically while clicking the remove button.](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtfo6?file=/demo.js:1465-1476)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can add another state value to hold your options for the `Select` component

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-2rqy5

If you want age to continue to be word based rather than numeric, your state could hold an array of objects such as

```
[
  {value: 10, display: 'Ten'},
  {value: 20, display: 'Twenty'},
  {value: 30, display: 'Thirty'}
]
```

But then you run into issues where how do you determine what to display?
Does each additional option add 1 year to age? 5? 10? you can change the function below to whatever you need it to be

```
export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([10, 20, 30])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  // Adds a new option (assuming you want to continue the decade trend)
  const addOption = () => {
    setOptions([
      ...options,
      (options.length + 1) * 10,
    ])
  }

  const removeOption = () => {
     // Because you cannot mutate state, create a copy of the array
     const newOptions = [...options]
     // Pop the last element off (we don't care about it, so it goes nowhere)
     newOptions.pop()
     // Set the options to the modified array
     setOptions(newOptions)
  }

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {/* Here, we map through our options to add them to the select */}
          {options.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
          )}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <Button 
        variant='contained'
        onClick={addOption}
      >
        Add Option
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant='contained'
        onClick={removeOption}
      >
        Remove Option
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```